# Special functions as representations of Lie Groups

Tags: special-functions, lie-groups

-The spherical harmonics $Y_{lm}$ are complete on $L^2(S^2)$.  They are also a representation of the (compact) Lie group $SO_3 (\mathbf{R})$.

-The functions $e^{i n x}$ are complete on $L^2([0,2\pi])$.  They are also a representation of the (compact) Lie group $U(1).$

My question is basically, how general is this phenomenon?  More specifically,

1. Bessel functions, Hermite polynomials, Legendre polynomials - do each of these represent some Lie group?  If so, what is it in each case?
2. Is there a nice example of some complete functions that represent a non-compact Lie group?
3. Is there a nice example of some complete functions that do not represent any Lie group at all?

Thanks!

Comment: A. Klimyk and N. Vilenkin, Studied this in their 3 volume [monography](http://www.amazon.com/Representation-Groups-Special-Functions-Representations/dp/0792314921). They also cover $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ and $SU(1,1)$ which are not compact.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I looked at Klimyk and Vilenkin, and I'm sure that the answers to my questions are in there somewhere.  However, these books are too advanced for me and I had trouble finding the answers to my questions.  Can anyone help out with a more specific answer, or a more basic reference?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Relation_to_spherical_harmonics_and_Legendre_polynomials

Comment: I think you guys would find this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163032/geometric-intuitive-meaning-of-sl2-r-su2-etc-representation-the interesting

Answer (score -1):

The representations of $SO(3)$ are indexed by numbers $|\ell, m \rangle$ where $\ell \in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$ and $|m| \leq \ell$ with $m - \ell \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The matrix elements of Wigner's small matrix give the Legendre polynomials:

$$ \langle \ell, 0 | e^{-i \theta J_z }|\ell, 0 \rangle = P_\ell(\cos \theta)$$

Here $J_z$ is a generator of the $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ Lie Algebra and the exponent is a rotation , $e^{-i \theta J_z } \in SO(3)$.